# PHP How to access argument of function inside anonymous function?

Tags: php

I need to access the first argument to a function inside an anonymous function passed as the second argument to said function.
For example:

```
<?php
function a($arg, $func) {
    echo $func();
}
a("argument 1", function () use($arg) {return $arg;});
?>
```

The above will return the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: arg in path/to/file.php on line 5
```

While the desired result would be:

```
argument 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below solution:

```
function a($arg, $func) {
    echo $func($arg);
}
a("argument 1", function ($arg) {return $arg;});
```

**output**

```
argument 1
```

for more detail have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php